# Ignore li with specific class in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have each loop for li tags but i do not want to include li tags with class pending. Right now my each loop is working for li tags
Here is my code

```
jQuery('ul li').each(function(){
  alert(jQuery(this).find('.title').text());
});
```

I have few li tags with class pending and i do not want to include these in above each loop. How i can do this?
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're expected to do significant research before posting. If you do any research on http://api.jquery.com, you'll find answers to this question (there are at least a couple). Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go before posting.

Comment: Can there be more than one `.title` in each `li`?

Comment: No there is only one .title in each li tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:not` selector

```
jQuery('ul li:not(.pending)').each(function(){
  alert(jQuery(this).find('.title').text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if` should suffice, using jQuery's `hasClass` method:

```
jQuery('ul li').each(function({
  if (!this.hasClass('pending') {
    alert(jQuery(this).find('.title').text());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hasClass() function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('ul li').each(function(){
  if(!jQuery(this).hasClass("pending"))
    alert(jQuery(this).find('.title').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><span class="title">afea</span></li>
<li class="pending"><span class="title">ffdf</span></li>
<li><span class="title">afdsfsffea</span></li>
</ul>
```